# 2D движение персонажа с реактивным ранцем

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет.
Хочу переработать свою плохую механику движения игрока.
Сначала поясню что мне нужно. Игрок имеет нормальную гравитацию. Ходит горизонтально, вправо и лево(как бы это парадоксально не звучало). Прыгать при этом он не умеет. Вместо прыжка я хочу реализовать подобие реактивного ранца, который подымает игрока, если ему надо вверх. При этом я хочу сохранить горизонтальное движение. В моём старом коде я обнулял старое движение и делал новое.  Работает вам скажу так себе.

```
public void MoveUp()
{
    direction = Vector2.zero;
    currentSpeed = rigidBody.velocity.magnitude;
    maxSpeed = maxDefault + (UpgradeComponents.Instance.GetLevelComponent(UpgradeComponents.ComponentShip.Engine) * 0.5f);

    if(currentSpeed <= maxSpeed) 
        rigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * force * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}

public void HorizontalMovement(Vector2 sideDirection)
{
    moveSpeed = defaultSpeed + (UpgradeComponents.Instance.GetLevelComponent(UpgradeComponents.ComponentShip.Engine) * 0.20f);
    direction = Vector2.zero;
    direction = sideDirection;
    direction *= moveSpeed; 
    direction.y = rigidBody.velocity.y;
    rigidBody.velocity = direction;
}
```

Вот старый код, который работал через кнопки.

Сейчас же я удалил кнопки и хочу сделать через джойстик. Создал джойстик и настроил его. Работает круто, как мне нужно. От него приходит Vector2 с направлением движения.

> Direction player - (0.5, 0.7) - max value (1, 1)

Что говорит - позиция джойстика в правом верхнем углу, то есть игрок должен лететь в правый верхний угол. Как мне правильно реализовать движение игрока, учитывая все мои условия? Также у меня есть speed и force игрока, которые я сейчас не знаю как мне использовать. Но я хотел бы влиять на эти параметры в дальнейшем(прокачка игрока). Помогите кто знает или есть какие то идее в каком направление двигаться.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnMovement(Vector2 direction)
{
    // for visibility inspector
    x = direction.x;
    y = direction.y;

    if (direction.y >= 0.42f && direction.y <= 0.5f)
    {
        if (rigidBody.gravityScale == 1)
            rigidBody.gravityScale = 0;

        transform.Translate(direction * (speed / 2) * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log("Slow fly!");
    }
    else if (direction.y >= 0.6f)
    {
        if (rigidBody.gravityScale == 1)
            rigidBody.gravityScale = 0;

        transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log("Faster fly!");
    }
    else
    {
        if (rigidBody.gravityScale != 1)
            rigidBody.gravityScale = 1;

        transform.Translate(new Vector2(direction.x, 0) * (speed / 1.5f) * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log("I must walk!");
    }
}
```

Вот так как то я сделал. Пока более менее устраивает, но нужно ещё немного доработать.